# How to make a function using Carbon in Lumen to check if current time is between 11pm to 7am?

Tags: php, laravel, lumen

This information can be found [in the Carbon docs](http://carbon.nesbot.com/docs/#api-comparison). How to implement this?

> To determine if the current instance is between two other instances you can use the aptly named `between()` method. The third parameter indicates if an equal to comparison should be done. The default is true which determines if its between or equal to the boundaries.
>
> ```
> $first = Carbon::create(2012, 9, 5, 1);
> $second = Carbon::create(2012, 9, 5, 5);
> var_dump(Carbon::create(2012, 9, 5, 3)->between($first, $second));          // bool(true)
> var_dump(Carbon::create(2012, 9, 5, 5)->between($first, $second));          // bool(true)
> var_dump(Carbon::create(2012, 9, 5, 5)->between($first, $second, false));   // bool(false)
> ```

Comment: Your implementation is correct, what seems to be the problem?

Comment: What part of the documentation is unclear?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since your time period crosses the day mark, it might be easier to check the opposite:

```
$first = Carbon::now()->setTime(7,0,0);
$second = Carbon::now()->setTime(23,0,0);
$now = Carbon::now();

if(!$now->between($first, $second)) {
    // Time is not between 7am and 11pm, so do your checks here
}
```